# jquery, how to find the parent div id?

Tags: jquery, hide, parent

im trying to hide the parent div that contains the clicked link:

```
<div  class="user" id="request_1">
    <div class="information">
       <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="approve_friends agree">Agree1</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div> 
<div  class="user" id="request_2">
    <div class="information">
       <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="approve_friends agree">Agree3</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div  class="user" id="request_3">
    <div class="information">
       <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="approve_friends agree">Agree4</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div> 

$('.agree').live("click", function(){
        var currentId2 = $(this).parent("div:second").attr('id');
        alert (currentId2);
       $('#'.currentId).hide('slow');
});
```

so when i click on the `Agree1`, i want to hide the corespondent div with id `request_1`

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YThmH/).

any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used parents instead of parent, and the line where you hide the element needed a + sign, not a dot.

```
$('.agree').live("click", function(){
        var currentId2 = $(this).parents(".user").attr('id');
        alert (currentId2);
       $('#' + currentId2).hide('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YThmH/1/

Comment: that worked, every answer worked but mine :)  the dot came from php, toooo much php

Answer (score 5):

```
$(this).closest("div.user").hide('slow');
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do this:

```
$('.agree').live("click", function(){
 $(this).parents('div.user').hide('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

parent() only go up one level, parent('div:second') means

1. go up one level and select this parent
2. on the set you have now (which contain only the `<li>` at that point), take the second div and discard the rest (so you end up with an empty set).

You need to use [parents(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) which means take all parents from where I am to the top, filtered by the selector.

> The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

This code work as intended:
http://jsfiddle.net/YThmH/3/